# Finding a switch for dining room ceiling wires

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture

I bought a house and there is a spot in the dining room for a ceiling light (it was capped off) and I installed a chandelier after determining the wires were not live and there is no switch that I can find that would control the light. The wires are not live. I checked the circuit breaker and there is none turned off or marked for the dining room. How can I locate the switch?

Comment: Are there any blank covers on the walls in the room? What about right outside the room?

Answer (score 1):

Many times if a owner wants to save $ up front we put a blank plat over the fixture location but there is normally a switch near by that wire is pulled to. If you don’t have a blank still pull any switches out and look for the unused conductors in the box. This might mean you need to purchase a single gang double switch but I have done this a few times.

Answer (score 0):

As Ed Beal suggests, look inside any switch boxes which are at reasonable locations to control that light. Especially for switches that now operate receptacles.

If the house is older, also look for switches or switch locations *outside* the room.  It was once fashionable to have the switch not inside the room at all, but just outside.